# Warp Text in Adobe flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, photoshop

I cannot find a solution to have Warp Text feature for Adobe Flex. I like to have Warp text in photoshop to be in Adobe flex.

[image: Warp Text]

Comment: Is this useful? http://www.softpeople.fr/Ressources/as3/curveText/curveText.html

Comment: @ContentiousMaximus Hello Maximus thanks for the curve feature but if u see I cant able to get other style features like Pinch, Archway etc which is present in photoshop and Illustrator(Wrap Text) i search for other features to be embedded in flex but it was vain

Comment: there's this one too, http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/AS3-dynamic-text-field-to-curve-textfield-on-an-arcing-path Anyway, I never heard about a similar native feature...

Comment: @ContentiousMaximus Yes Maximus here we have only curve i referred this example before but rest of the features i can't able to get.....Please refer this website http://www.bluecotton.com/studio.html?target=175&garColor=9&designFile=&ranNum=0.640281371772289 where please select Add text in that select Shape we have different styles

Comment: @ContentiousMaximus I want the text style features which is very hard to get just like bluecotton