# Can we add the Word Art style in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

Can we add the WORD ART or WARP TEXT style in flex

[image]

[image]

etc

Just like these images i want to make test  like bottom arcs, vertical arcs, Birdseye etc as as shown in the images above.

Please help me is that possible in Flex to make such text fonts styles

Comment: Does this tread any ground different than your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972875/warp-text-in-adobe-flex ?

Comment: @wvxvw good clue you have given can we use PixelBlender for Word Art effect on text .

Comment: wvxvw is on the right path with Pixel Bender. It is very low level and difficult to understand, but it can definitely do what you need to do and it is incredibly fast. You would have to pass it BitmapData and transform it, but you can do it with this method (assuming you can figure out the math to warp the images or can find a premade PBJ file that does it)

Comment: You can also use Adobe's TLF (text layout framework) to render text on  a curved (or other) path. Don't have time to whip up an example right now, but maybe someone else does :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do an envelope distort

[envelope-distort-with-actionscript](http://www.neuroproductions.be/experiments/envelope-distort-with-actionscript/) ([download source](http://www.neuroproductions.be/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=17))

First you will draw your textfield to a bitmap using the myBitmap.draw(myTextField). Then you will use the code below to distort that bitmap.

You can either let the user control it or you could set the handles visible to false and set their x,y to preset positions to achieve different effects.

Are you building a tshirt design tool? I created one of those years ago and had effects like this.

[image: envelope-distort]

Comment: First of all thank you so much for the answer.....Yes I am trying to design a shirt in online where the word art style can be added you have given a good link as I am going to check it out...Will come back to you for further classification

Comment: I would build a new component called wordart and use the linked source code above as the bases for that component. You can still use pure actionscript in a flex project. This code should create a bitmap/bitmapData that you can map to an image component for display.

Comment: that is a great solution. It is not user controllable but perfect if all you want our the standard wordart effects

Answer (score 1):

I have found a link where we can obtain the word art style in flash which will be very useful for all  [click here](http://wonderfl.net/c/nX72/)

Comment: As mentioned I am trying to obtain the features in flex